# ClassCastException Issue with deploying spring boot war in WAS 8.5.5.16 but works in tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, websphere

When trying to deploy our spring boot war into the WAS 8.5.5.16 application server(aka) Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.16 is giving the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.el.ExpressionFactory
at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:210)
at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:118)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.<clinit>(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:65)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getJspApplicationContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:267)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:62)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:143)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:111)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1736)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:415)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1462)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:641)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1040)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2279)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5572)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5698)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2284)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
```

My pom.xml is as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxx.dart</groupId>
    <artifactId>YYY</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ZZZ</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>

    </parent>
    <properties>
    
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
        <swagger.version>2.8.0</swagger.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss'Z'</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.1</jacoco.version>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <!-- jacoco plugin to run junit tests coverage -->
        <jacoco.version>0.8.6</jacoco.version>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>21.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.basics -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->

                            <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>target/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/webapp/lib</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0.1254</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <format>{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss'Z'}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>timestamp</item>
                    </items>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.5.2,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IT*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <!--final name -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Few weeks back this configuration was working and we were able to deploy our app, but something happened and this is not working anymore. Key points

1. we are having parent last in the websphere
2. we are able to reproduce it in all environments ( though unfortunately it started in production)
3. We did recently migrate to open jdk ( with adopt ) though i am not sure whether thats causing this issue.

Any help is deeply appreciated.  i believe this is because of some Websphere issue but not able to point it out exactly.  if we can disable this jsf thats also fine as our front end is a angular application

Comment: WebSphere Application Server doesn't support running on openjdk (or adopt) so what do you mean when you say you migrated to openjdk?

Comment: Do you have any change history around the "something happened" that you could use to narrow down the change that was responsible? Just from looking at the exception and pom.xml, my guess is that the inclusion of the javax.el API is your problem - in a parent-last configuration, you're vulnerable to a conflict between the server's version and a version you package in the app, and it would be worth testing to see if removing it from the app fixes the problem.

Comment: @Alasdair we were building using oracle jdk and later switched to open jdk but we are running with whatever jre that gets bundled with websphere. Following are the System.out `code` WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.16 [ND 8.5.5.16 cf161930.02] [IBMJAVA8 8.0.4.5 cf121726.01] running with process name XXX and process id 11967
Full server name is XXX
Host Operating System is Linux, version 2.6.32-754.41.2.el6.x86_64
Java version = 1.8.0_211, Java Runtime Version = 8.0.5.37 - pxa6480sr5fp37-20190618_01(SR5 FP37), Java Compiler = j9jit29, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
`code`

Comment: @Jarid - javax.el was always there. The exception that i see doesn't correspond to the javax.el.ExpressionFactory of javax.el-api (code line) so my feeling is that its using Websphere's ExpressionFactory - all those things were working earlier

Comment: The fact that it appears to be using WebSphere's ExpressionFactory would make it more likely that's the issue - ExpressionFactory (from WAS) tries to get an implementation, which finds ExpressionFactoryImpl from the app, which links to ExpressionFactory from the app, and the cast fails (because the same class from separate class loaders cannot be cast to each other). There are some APIs where you can't bring your own version because it will conflict with the server's copy, and it's possible EL is one of them.

Comment: Issue is that if i take off the `code` <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>`code` then i get ClassNotFoundException `code`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager`code`

Comment: Switched back to an older version that was built with oracle jdk and its not working now. same error. am totally stuck

Comment: so really if i take out el dependency i get classnotfoundexception , if i put it there i get classcastexception. catch-22 situation.

Comment: @Jarid, since i have chosen parent last it should first use my ExpressionFactory and my ExpressionFactoryImpl , but for some reason its using webspheres' ExpressionFactory ( i know for sure since the line nos dont correspond to the ExpressionFactory that i have in my project.

Comment: For many Java EE APIs (possibly including EL; I know it applies to JSP and Servlet), the API is utilized at the container level, meaning that you can't override the API with your own version - the web container will reference the API and attempt to use objects of that type from the application. In that case, the application can't include its own copy of the API, because the container needs to access a consistent version of the class.

Comment: As for the NoClassDefFoundError when you remove the library... it's possible that means that you can't run an app that relies on EL 3.0 for that level of WAS. WAS 8.5.5 implements Java EE 6, which includes Expression Language 2.2, and the class you're "missing" was added in 3.0. You might need to remove that dependency, or move to a newer level of WAS (WAS 9 implements Java EE 7, which includes Expression Language 3.0).

Comment: I had to downgrade to spring boot  1.5.12.RELEASE and after this downgrade it started to work. I am still struggling what changed in any of the 8.5.5 patches that is causing it to fail for 2.0.0 spring boot. Moving to a newer version or going to undertow are the two options that we are considering.

Comment: Found the issue, we are including spring-boot-starter-validation and one of its components is the tomcat-embed-el. Had to do the following in my pom to make it work . Had to exclude it in the starter-validation and include it specifically as provided scope (or else it wont work with tomcat). with this i was able to get it to work both in tomcat and WAS now. Still don't know why this issue cropped up recently . My guess is one of the recent patch is starting this conflict.

Comment: @Jarid- we have decided to move to websphere liberty and/or undertow as we also had to migrate to java 11 . I hope we don't see the issues that we are seeing with WAS in either of these app servers. Any comments ?